# Is it possible to compare two AES encrypted string in iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, aes

I have two NSStrings, they are AES256 encrypted. Is it possible to compare these two encrypted strings?

```
NSString *passKey = @"mykey";

NSData *data = [@"string to encrypt" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSData *encryptedData1 = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:passKey
                                           error:&error];

NSData *encryptedData2 = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:passKey
                                           error:&error];

NSString *aesEncryptedString1  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *aesEencryptedString2  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData2 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"aesEencryptedString1 is %@",encryptedstring1);
NSLog(@"aesEencryptedString2 is %@",encryptedstring2);

if ([aesEncryptedString1 isEqualToString:aesEencryptedString2])
{
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Comment: It is possible.. if that's what you want...

Comment: I am not able to do that. I am encrypting same string twice with same key. Then I tried to compare the data. but it fails :(

Comment: You should show how you do that (code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after you've included the code it appears that you're using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor):

Your encryption generates:

> This generates an NSData including a header, encryption salt, HMAC
>   salt, **IV**, ciphertext, and HMAC

So yes, you need to decrypt in order to compare. You can read about [IV here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) and also a good discussion [ecb vs cbc](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/08/encryption-operating-modes-ecb-vs-cbc/)

Comment: I want to compare the encrypted strings. In fact these 2 strings are encrypted in 2 different devices, collected together and we need to compare the 2 strings to initiate some process.

Comment: @AdarshVC: Do you have some specific reason you don't want to decrypt them and compare? Given your use case I don't see a valid reason not to. It would be much easier and more secure to decrypt and compare than to change the mode to ECB.

Comment: @AdarshVC You'll have to change encrypting algorithm. Also added link to a good discussion ecb vs cbc

Comment: Allowing encrypted strings to be compared drastically reduces the security of the encryption, which is why RNCryptor does not support it directly. Designing a reasonably secure encryption scheme that still allows comparison would require more details about the specific system requirements. (It's easy to build an insecure encryption scheme with this property. The challenge is doing it without sacrificing more security than is required.)

Comment: Note that there is absolutely no reason to use ECB to achieve this goal. CBC is perfectly capable of being compared if provide a constant IV. ECB has significant security problems beyond comparability and should never be used for encrypting anything but random data.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. It depends on the mode, padding, key, and IV (if applicable) that were used during encryption. Assuming the same key and padding are used...

- If the mode is ECB, then yes, you can compare strings of the cipher text like this.
- If the mode is CBC (or any other mode that uses an IV), and a random IV is used for each encryption, then no, comparing strings like this will not work because two identical strings will encrypt to different cipher text. The only way to compare in this case is to decrypt the strings.
- If the mode is CBC (or any other mode that uses an IV), and you use a fixed IV, then yes, you can compare strings of the cipher text.

**Update**

Thanks for posting the code. Given your comments, I'd reconsider if you even need to be using encryption for your use case. If this is for authentication a hashing algorithm or Key Derivation Function may be more appropriate.

Comment: Do you ever need to decrypt the text? From your other comments it sounds like you don't.

Comment: I don't want to decrypt the text.